# Future code affecting state at an earlier point in time?

Tags: java, methods, stack, comments

(EDIT: Please note that TwoStacksAsQueue's and ArrayList's add() methods are different, so there are no recursive calls happening. I am still stuck after using the debugger, which is why I am asking for help here.)

I am in the middle of designing a class of two stacks that functions as a queue. When I run it, the last number it prints is 6 as expected. When I uncomment the last three lines of code, however, it prints 3 instead.

The way I see it, it should make no difference if the while loop at the end of the `transfer()` method is commented out or not. It comes after the print statement, so how could it possibly affect the output? What am I missing here? I have reduced my code to the minimal reproducible example.

```
public class TwoStacksAsQueue<T> {
    final int stackCapacity;
    final Stack<T> stack1;
    final Stack<T> stack2;

    public TwoStacksAsQueue(int stackCapacity) {
        this.stackCapacity = stackCapacity;
        stack1 = new Stack<>();
        stack2 = new Stack<>();
    }

    public void add(T something) {
        if (stack1.size() + stack2.size() >= stackCapacity * 2)
            throw new RuntimeException("Not enough room in either stack; cannot add");
        else if (stack1.isEmpty()) {
            stack1.push(something);
        } else {
            int size = stack1.size();
            List<T> popped = new ArrayList<>();
            while (!stack1.isEmpty()) popped.add(stack1.pop());
            stack1.push(something);
            for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) stack1.push(popped.get(i));
            if (stack1.size() > stackCapacity) transfer(stack1, stack2);
        }
    }

    private void transfer(Stack<T> from, Stack<T> to) {
        List<T> popped = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(from.size());
//        while (from.size() > stackCapacity) {
//            popped.add(from.pop());
//        }
    }
}
```

main method:

```
TwoStacksAsQueue<Integer> twoStacksAsQueue = new TwoStacksAsQueue<>(3);
twoStacksAsQueue.add(0);
twoStacksAsQueue.add(1);
twoStacksAsQueue.add(2);
twoStacksAsQueue.add(3);
twoStacksAsQueue.add(4);
twoStacksAsQueue.add(5);
```

Comment: I can't really follow your code, but I did notice that `add` calls itself, as well as calling `transfer`.  So you can get multiple calls to `transfer`.  Perhaps the absence or presence of those three lines affects subsequent calls to `transfer`.  Honestly, the best way for you to work this out would be to step through the code with your debugger.

Comment: You probably don't have a magical computer where code that's going to be running in the future affects the state in the past. So that's definitely not what's happening.

Comment: @Jesper And yet there we are...

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem My TwoStacksAsQueue class's add() method is unrelated to the add() method in ArrayList, so this is not a case of the same method calling itself. Add() does call transfer(), but this by itself would not account for any bugs. What I have in the main method is purely for initializing a TwoStacksAsQueue object. Since the source of the bug lies in the presence or absence of those three lines of code, I am not sure how a debugger will help. I know they do cause the from stack to shrink, but not until after the from stack's size has already been printed!

Comment: Right, I see that.  I misread your code.  However, my advice to use a debugger still stands.  My experience is that stepping through code with a debugger often reveals unexpected behaviour and can provide great insight into what's really going on.

Comment: "I am not sure how a debugger will help" - for one thing, it might help you see that some of your assumptions are wrong (e.g. the stack may not contain the number of elements you think it contains). What are the outputs before the final output? That might be a clue too. "how could it possibly affect the output" - well, you are calling add (and thus transfer) repeatedly, and in transfer, you throw away elements each time. The while loop effectively put's a cap on the number of elements.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thanks. I will edit my code a little more and use the debugger to isolate the cause of the problem.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović ArrayList's add() method is different from TwoStacksAsQueue's add () method. The debugger has shown unexpected output and I modify the code accordingly, only to get even more unexpected results. Ever since getting a new computer, this is not the first time Intellij has appeared to be running lines of code out of order.

Comment: I was talking about the TwoStacksAsQueue's add() method (it calls transfer() ). You can test your hypothesis that something is wrong with your computer by running the code on a different computer (e.g. search online for a "Java REPL" or an online Java compiler or something along those lines, and run your code there, see what happens). Speaking from experience, 99.9% of the time, when you think that there's something wrong with the computer/compiler, it turns out that the erroneous behavior is only apparent and that it's your fault (it does what it does because you inadvertedly *told* it to).

Comment: Oh, BTW - and I'm sorry if you already know how to do this, but just in case - when you say you used the debugger, did you just set breakpoints and inspect values, or did you step through the code? In case you're not that well versed with this stuff: the debugger allows you to step through statements line by line ("step over"), and go inside of functions ("step into"), so you can execute the code line by line and (hopefully) see exactly where the unexpected change happens. You can look up online how to do this in your IDE.

Comment: P.S. "there are no recursive calls happening" - Oh, I just read your edit, so now I understand why you replied with "ArrayList's add() method is different from TwoStacksAsQueue's add ()". But you misunderstood me; I'm not saying there are recursive calls. I was saying that *you* are calling add() repeatedly, which in turn calls transfer() after the few initial calls. You are doing: `twoStacksAsQueue.add(0); ... twoStacksAsQueue.add(5);` - it's like a "manual" loop. So it eventually results in: `add(3) transfer(...) add(4) transfer(...) add(5) transfer(...)`

Comment: Filip, it's my fault we're discussing recursive calls.  I skimmed over the code when it was first posted, saw that `add` called `add`, but didn't realise it was `add` from two different classes.

Comment: I do not think I am explaining my question well, but I do not think the prior calls to add() are at issue here. They were necessary to initialize the two stacks for the TwoStacksAsArray object. My code is a little sloppy, to be sure, so I will attempt to rewrite it and spend more time with the debugger. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The commented out lines of code change the behavior when the `stackCapacity` is exceeded. In your example, that happens when you push the fourth item. You should focus your debugging efforts there instead of waiting until the sixth item is pushed. If you think that code shouldn't be triggered until you hit twice the `stackCapacity`, you need to rethink that part.

Your code is hard to follow. In particular, I can't tell why you are creating temporary `popped` lists instead of using `stack2`. It seems like you think you are transferring values onto `stack2`, but you are actually putting them in a temporary `popped` list that then goes out of scope. You'll have an easier time debugging by printing out all the elements of `stack1` and `stack2` than trying to discern something based on the size.